# Logarithmic bar plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, horizontal-alignment

I'm currently trying to create a diagram, with a logarithmic scale on y axis. This mostly works, except that the value of `nodes near coords` is wrong. Without `ymode=log` it shows e.g. 20551 as label. With `ymode=log` it shows 9.93. Is it possible to get behaviour of linear mode? (So it displays again 20551 instead of 9.93)

And is it possible to get legend automatically centered?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=0.8\textwidth,
    ybar,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    ylabel={\#Pathes},
    ymode=log,
    log ticks with fixed point,
    xlabel={Test},
    symbolic x coords={1 - 10, 11 - 100, 101 - 1000, 1001 - 10000, >10000},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}},
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    legend style={at={(0,-2.5em)}, draw=none, anchor=north, legend columns=-1, legend     style={/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}}}
]
    \addplot coordinates {(1 - 10, 20551) (11 - 100, 19784) (101 - 1000, 2436) (1001 - 10000, 149) (>10000, 12)};
    \addplot coordinates {(1 - 10,4) (11 - 100,4) (101 - 1000,4) (1001 - 10000, 0) (>10000, 0)};
\legend{used,understood,not understood}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Current output:
[image: Current output]

Wanted output:
[image: Wanted output]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you by completing your code to create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) as that makes it much easier to understand your question and reproduce the problem.

Comment: @SunBlack: You can center the legend using `at={(current axis.south)}, below=6ex`. Sorry for missing that part of the question (the duplicate I linked to only covers the logarithm part). In general, it's best to only have a single question per post.

Comment: The question has been reopened. The part about the labels in logarithmic plots has been answered in [nodes near coords with logarithmic axis: Wrong values](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142965/nodes-near-coords-with-logarithmic-axis-wrong-values/142967#142967). Could you edit your question to remove that part and focus on the legend positioning?

Answer (score 1):

You can center `legend` placing it at position `0.5` (without units) which represents the  the mid point of each axis. You can also the legend anchor.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width=0.8\textwidth,
    ybar,
    enlargelimits=0.15,
    ylabel={\#Pathes},
    ymode=log,
    log ticks with fixed point,
    xlabel={Test},
    symbolic x coords={1 - 10, 11 - 100, 101 - 1000, 1001 - 10000, >10000},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords={\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotspointmeta}},
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    legend style={at={(0.5,-2.75em)},anchor=north, draw=none, anchor=north, legend columns=-1, legend  style={/tikz/every even column/.append style={column sep=0.5cm}}}
]
    \addplot coordinates {(1 - 10, 20551) (11 - 100, 19784) (101 - 1000, 2436) (1001 - 10000, 149) (>10000, 12)};
    \addplot coordinates {(1 - 10,4) (11 - 100,4) (101 - 1000,4) (1001 - 10000, 0) (>10000, 0)};
\legend{used,understood,not understood}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]