# pgfplots log y axis with normal nodes

Tags: pgfplots

Due to my dataset having some values much greater than others, I tried using the log scale on Y axis. How can I display my data as is, meaning 40 on the first bar, 42.69 on the second, etc?

```
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        [ybar=2pt,
        width=16cm, height=8cm,
        bar width=8pt,
        enlarge x limits=0.1,
        enlarge y limits=0.25,
        legend style={at={(0.5,0.95)}, anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
        ylabel={Delay (us)},
        ymode=log,
        symbolic x coords={1p Bare C,1p Partikle,2p Bare C,2p Partikle,2p Bare C \& Partikle,2p Bare C Sampling,2p Bare C Queuing},
        x tick label style={rotate=20,anchor=east},
        xtick=data,
        nodes near coords,
        every node near coord/.append style={rotate=90, anchor=west}]
    \addplot coordinates {(1p Bare C,40)    (1p Partikle,29)     (2p Bare C,17)    (2p Partikle,22)    (2p Bare C \& Partikle,19)    (2p Bare C Sampling,193) (2p Bare C Queuing,448)};
    \addplot coordinates {(1p Bare C,42.69)    (1p Partikle,33.19)     (2p Bare C,24.25)    (2p Partikle,26.06)    (2p Bare C \& Partikle,20.63)    (2p Bare C Sampling,360.63) (2p Bare C Queuing,670.94)};
    \addplot coordinates {(1p Bare C,47)    (1p Partikle,36)     (2p Bare C,45)    (2p Partikle,42)    (2p Bare C \& Partikle,29)    (2p Bare C Sampling,476) (2p Bare C Queuing,1050)};
    \addplot coordinates {(1p Bare C,1.44)    (1p Partikle,1.31)     (2p Bare C,6.13)    (2p Partikle,4.48)    (2p Bare C \& Partikle,1.23)    (2p Bare C Sampling,64.66) (2p Bare C Queuing,128.67)};
    \legend{Min,Average,Max,Avg. Deviation}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{All test case delays for 128 byte transfers.}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site! I guess http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142965/nodes-near-coords-with-logarithmic-axis-wrong-values will answer your question? (Just use `point meta=rawy` instead of `rawx`.)

Comment: Thanks a lot  Torbjørn! I guess I was searching with the wrong terms. Is there any way I can make this question useful for others?

Comment: We could close this as a duplicate of the other. Questions closed as dupes are still visible, so anyone finding this question will be referred to the other. I can also edit Jake's answer there to explicitly mention `rawy` for `ybar`.

Comment: I'm all good for that since the topic would be fully covered by the linked question. Thanks again!